# How to access the struct elements in a array of vectors of struct?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, struct

I am new to vectors, but they seem fairly straight forward. I am working off of a profs code and she is allocating an array of vectors[n]. I would like to be able to allocate the elements in the struct on each element in the array.
The struct is called edge

```
struct edge {
   int vertex1;
   int vertex2;
   int weight;
};

Adj = new vector<edge>[n];
```

Now I want to be able to allocate vertex1, 2 and weight to each vector for each element of the array. I can't find the right syntax for this.
something along the lines of:

```
Adj[1].vertex1 = 11;
Adj[1].vertex2 = 20; 
Adj[1].weight = 40;
```

however also specifying their location in the array.
Thanks!!

Comment: `new vector<edge>[n];` is extremely bad form for a C++ codebase. That can just be  `std::vector<std::vector<edge>> Adj(n);` instead (and avoids all the hassle of manually managing the memory). Though the way you describe your inteded usage looks like you just want a `std::vector<edge>`, not a nested one

Answer (score 0):

If you want a new element to be inserted into the vector, you need to use `push_back`:

```
std::vector<edge> Adj;
Adj.push_back(Edge{11, 20, 40});
```

Either that, or you can pre-allocate a given number of elements (by passing the ctor the number of elements).

Note that C++ vectors are 0-indexed in the `std` library.

Comment: You may wish to note that if declared as: `std::vector<edge> Adj(3);` for instance, it is acceptable to write `Adj[1] = Edge { 11, 20, 40 };`